# Why doesn't counting files with "for file in $0/*; let i=$i+1; done" work?

Tags: shell, terminal, scripting

I'm new in ShellScripting and have the following script that i created based on a simpler one, i want to pass it an argument with the path to count files. Cannot find my logical mistake to make it work right, the output is always "1"

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0

for file in $0/*
do
    let i=$i+1
done

echo $i
```

To execute the code i use

```
sh scriptname.sh /path/to/folder/to/count/files
```

Comment: See the entry for `let` in http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Thank you for the info, i'll read it in a while :)

Answer (score 1):

`$0` is the name with which your script was invoked (roughly, subject to several exceptions that aren't pertinent here). The first argument is `$1`, and so it's `$1` that you want to use in your glob expression.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
for file in "$1"/*; do
    i=$(( i + 1 ))      ## $(( )) is POSIX-compliant arithmetic syntax; let is deprecated.
done

echo "$i"
```

That said, you can get this number more directly:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob   # allow globs to expand to an empty list
files=( "$1"/* )    # put list of files into an array
echo "${#files[@]}" # count the number of items in the array
```

...or even:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -- "$1"/*                        # override $@ with the list of files matching the glob
if [ -e "$1" ] || [ -L "$1" ]; then  # if $1 exists, then it had matches
  echo "$#"                          # ...so emit their number.
else
  echo 0                             # otherwise, our result is 0.
fi
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly and it's a great comment to learn some little things :)

Comment: Note that in the first one I didn't handle the case where the directory is empty -- it'll return 1 there, whereas the latter two will return 0 (because they either use `nullglob` or the test for `-e` / `-L`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of files in a directory, you can run something like this:

`ls /path/to/folder/to/count/files | wc -l`

Comment: it's for a working example of a script that uses an argument. For personal use i would use that, but the college asks me for a script :(